# What is the borel set on $\mathbb R\coprod\mathbb R$?

Tags: measure-theory

What is the $\sigma -$algebra of the Borel set on $\mathbb R\coprod \mathbb R$, i.e. $$\{(i,x)\mid i\in \{1,2\}, x\in\mathbb R\}=\mathbb R^{\{1,2\}}.$$

I have to proposition :

1) Either I put the product topology, and thus the topology generated by $$C(B_1,B_2)=\{(i,x)\mid i\in B_1, x\in B_2\},$$
where $B_1\in \mathcal P(\{1,2\})$ and $B_2\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

2) Now, wouldn't it be interesting to put the topology generated by $$C(\{1,2\},B)=\{(i,x)\mid i\in \{1,2\}
 x\in B\} \ \ ?$$
It look to be the same than $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, is it true ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that $\mathbb R\coprod \mathbb R=\mathbb R^{1,2}$. Notice that $\mathbb R^{\{1,2\}}$ is really $\mathbb R^2$. Normally, $$\mathbb R\coprod \mathbb R=\{(i,x)\mid i\in\{1,2\}, x\in\mathbb R\}=\{i,j\}\times \mathbb R.$$
So this space is much smaller.

Now, $\{1\}\times \mathbb R$ is open in $\mathbb R\coprod \mathbb R$, but it's not open in $\mathbb R^{1,2}$. Now, you can indeed but the product topology, and you first intuition is the correct one, i.e. the topology generated by the projection, i.e. the open set are of the form $\{1\}\times O$ and $\{2\}\times O$ where $O$ is open in $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology.